# application not fit to the android virtual device

Tags: android

In my android application, I have a problem that when I run my application, its not fit to the emulator and some part cut on it like below:

[image]

And also you can see below I have a button also on it like below image:

[image]

But its not show me the full image, means a button is missing on the emulator.

How can I resolve it. kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: Which screen size emulator did you launch?

Comment: have you used ScrollView in your xml layout ?

Comment: Change to anothr emulator and yes.. use the comment above this one..

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your designer and emulator are using different screen dimensions.

You can change the designer to use the same screen dimensions. Currently, from your screen shot you're using the Nexus One layout. From what I can tell the emulator doesn't look like the Nexus One screen dimensions.

With Android it isn't as simple as 1 layout for all dimensions, screen sizes and devices. You have to implement multi-screen support to address this. You can usually do this by having a variance on dimensions, styles and layouts. A lot of the time one layout will work universally, but dimensions often need tweaking.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more on Supporting Multiple Screens.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem that can occur in real devices (remember, we have loads and loads of different screen sizes for android) so you definitely need to fix it.

The best way to avoid this is to wrap the entire layout inside a `ScrollView`, so the user can scroll to see all the content of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fit all the elements on the screen then you need to account for different screen sizes and densities. In your particular case you are building the screen on a different sized screen than the emulator.

Assuming you do not want the screen to scroll (which is solved using a ScrollView), then to fix this, you can do the following:

1. Build different XML layouts for different screen sizes
2. Use dimen files to specify different sizes for some or all elements on the screen so that they re-size depending on the screen size.
3. Use weighted LinearLayout so that Android re-sizes the elements according to the screen they are placed on.

Each of these is pretty easy to search and find various ways of doing.